# protoc-gen-go specific version require

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I need a  pre build project and I need a version of   `protoc-gen-go v1.25.0-devel`  but I am unable to find command etc to install It , till now I tried to do something like this :

```
go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.25.0-devel
```

and I am getting this  **ERROR**    `invalid version: unknown revision cmd/protoc-gen-go/v1.25.0-devel`

Is there any way to get this version ?

Comment: There is no such version as v1.25.0-devel. Check the available releases here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/tags. I ran `go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.25.0` and it works correctly

Comment: @PabloFlores  I need   `v1.25.0-devel`  not  `v1.25.0`

Comment: There are no tags nor branches with that name available, you're not going to get that specific version. You can try to point to a specific commit though

Comment: @PabloFlores  who he is working by using  this ? https://dev.to/greenteabiscuit/mini-grpc-project-creating-a-simple-increment-api-on-go-6cn

Comment: The person who wrote the post never specified any particular version for the protoc-gen-go package, it could be that `go get` downloaded the latest package available at the time or the one in their go mod cache. Try using the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following [this post](https://dev.to/greenteabiscuit/mini-grpc-project-creating-a-simple-increment-api-on-go-6cn) to create a sample service, you don't need the specific version 1.25.0-devel  that appears in the generated files. You should use the latest stable version (currently v1.26.0). Since it is an minor version upgrade, there should be no breaking changes between versions. One thing that you may need to make the examples in the post to work is that you should set the package for the generated code. You can set it in the .proto file as an option, for example `option go_package = grpc-example/generated/protos/calc` or as a command line argument for the protoc command, for example `protoc ...OTHER_OPTS   --go_opt=Mprotos/calc.proto=grpc-example/generated/protos/calc`.

If you are sure that you absolutely need the specific version v1.25.0-devel you can install the plugin pointing to a specific commit (as that version is not currently available as a tag/branch name). If you're using go 1.16.x you can use `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@a9513eb` pointing at [this commit](https://go.googlesource.com/protobuf/+/a9513ebdb86068803ccda83ded57e8330a72961e). For older go versions, use `go get`